# Hbase connects to localhost on remote server. Zookeper denies connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, apache-zookeeper, remote-server, centos8

We have been facing a rather strange issue on google cloud platform. We are trying to setup an Hbase standalone instance on google cloud with a static IP address and to connect remotely via Java API to the instance.

The code runs well if complied into a Jar and deployed on HBase server, however from local machine although it has all ports opened and full access, refuses connection via Zookeeper.

I have searched countless forums and have not been able to succeed.

Have changed the etc/hosts file, added zookeeper quorum in the hbase-site.xml but nothing has worked.

I have isolated problem to the fact that HBase only connects to Zookeeper via localhost and not external IP.

We are deploying this on CentOS 8.

Also to confirm it wasnt connectivity related we tried this on a virtual machine on a separate machine on LAN, AWS server but it seems there is something missing somewhere that it just doesnt want to work.

**Hbase-site.xml is as follows:**

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>ip of server</value></property>
  </property>
```

The error encountered during connection is :

```
2021-03-02 17:57:00,327 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=10.0.0.22:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@3dfa819
2021-03-02 17:57:00,332 INFO  [main] common.X509Util: Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2021-03-02 17:57:00,336 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2021-03-02 17:57:00,343 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2021-03-02 17:57:00,356 INFO  [main-SendThread(10.0.0.22:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server rd-hp-pav-2/10.0.0.22:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2021-03-02 17:57:00,358 INFO  [main-SendThread(10.0.0.22:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket error occurred: rd-hp-pav-2/10.0.0.22:2181: Connection refused
2021-03-02 17:57:01,460 INFO  [main-SendThread(10.0.0.22:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server rd-hp-pav-2/10.0.0.22:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

The etc/hosts file on server contains the following format:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
123.23.34.56 cloud.google.com.c1.hbase hbase
```

On the Web gui for HBase the following information is present and i can see it refers to localhost when all values have been changed in hbase-site.xml

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add in your **local** `/etc/hosts` file entry like

`public_ip_zookeeper/master    private_DNS_name_zookeeper/master`

I had a similar issue in aws. This solved it for me.